# RestEasy Spring Integration Error

Tags: spring, rest, resteasy

I am trying to integrate the RestEasy with Spring 4 as below:

web.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                    version="3.0">
    <display-name>RestEasy Webapp</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
                <context:annotation-config/>
                <context:component-scan base-package="lesson.resteasy"/>
</beans>
```

My dependencies configuration is as below: There are few more dependencies along.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

When deploying this to Tomcat after a clean build, I am getting the below error.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.SpringContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.SpringContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 09, 2015 10:47:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Feb 09, 2015 10:47:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

**Can you help me fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
```

not

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.SpringContextLoaderListener
```

hence the `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet, this fixed the problem. I had to add some more dependencies though. Thank you again.